# Can we find $n$ such that $p|2^n-1$ for a given prime $p.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For a given prime $p$ can we find a positive integer $n$ such that $p$ is a divisor of $2^n-1.$
I know, choosing a large $n$ we can do this. But is there any proof for this? I have no idea for start a proof. A hint would  be better. Thank you.

Comment: We add the condition : $p$ is odd.

Comment: @HeeKwonLee: I think for $p=2$ this is obvious.

Comment: @Nilan really? For $p=2$, it is obvious that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $2|2^n-1$? And what may that $n$ be?

Comment: @5xum: Obvious means, It is immediately we can that there is no such $n.$ However I should thanks to Hee Kwon Lee to show me this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a hint, how many different remainders can you get if you divide $2^n$ by $p$?

Comment: $p-1.$ Still I didn't get it.

Comment: Euler's totient function. $2^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \mod(n).$ Is it correct?

Comment: @Nilan The totient function, or Fermat's little theorem, will give you an answer. There are straightforward proofs of these results of course. But I was hinting at a more direct proof. The infinite set of values of $2^n$ is reduced to a finite set of remainders - what can you say if two values $2^n, 2^m$ have the same remainder? This is worth thinking about because the same kind of observation will help with other problems.

Comment: That is a new idea to me. I will think about it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple application of Fermat's little theorem. Let's say the given prime is odd, that is to say, $p \neq 2$, so therefore $\gcd(2, p) = 1$. From Fermat's little theorem, it follows that $n = p - 1$ has the desired property.

Just to be sure, work out three or four examples by hand or on a calculator. I'll do one for you: $p = 13$, so $n = p - 1 = 12$, then we see that $$\frac{2^{12} - 1}{13} = 315.$$